# Leg won't bend right

Tags: rigging

I want the backside of the knee to bend smoother.

Watch the backside of the knee
[image: Watch the backside of the knee]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be subdivided to work. Add a subdivision-surface modifier to the object being rigged, and set the view and render to about 3-4. Also, this should be set to simple subdividing if you want the geometry to look the same.

If it does not look the same, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in *Edit Mode*, and slide the loopcuts to the sides of the original geometry, this will fix your issue.